# Passing NULL as argument to a C macro

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to define a macro -

```
#define macro1(arg1) \
 do{ \
  int _state = 0; \
  if (arg1 && arg1->member_) \
    _state = arg1->member_->state_; \
  printf("%d", _state); \
 } while(0)

A *a = new A():
macro1(a);  // Works
macro1(NULL); // Error
```

The specific error I see is -

> "error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer"

Aren't we allowed to pass `NULL` as an argument to macros?

Comment: What does `NULL->member_` mean?  Do you know how macros work?  It's just text replacement.

Comment: So how would I achieve what I am trying to do. The arg1 might or might not be available when the macro is invoked. I need to send in a NULL value to satisfy the macro's definition. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Why use a macro? Seems like a function might work fine here.

Comment: C? Or C++? Please clarify. Both the languages are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro expansion is just text replacement, so when you passed `NULL`, it will expand to `NULL->member`, clearly it is an error. One way is to use a temporary variable for that:

```
#define macro1(arg1) \
 do{ \
  A* p = (arg1);
  int _state = 0; \
  if (p && p->member_) \
    _state = p->member_->state_; \
  printf("%d", _state); \
 } while(0)

A *a = new A():
macro1(a);
macro1(NULL);
```

This way both cases will work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand what's a macro in order to understand your mistake. Except for the compiler, there's an animal called pre-compiler. It replaces all the macros' references by the actual code defined for this macro. So this code:

```
#define macro1(arg1) \
 do{ \
  int _state = 0; \
  if (arg1 && arg1->member_) \
    _state = arg1->member_->state_; \
  printf("%d", _state); \
 } while(0)

A *a = new A():
macro1(a);  // Works
macro1(NULL); // Error
```

will be replaced with:

```
A *a = new A():
do{
  int _state = 0;
  if (a && a->member_)
    _state = a->member_->state_;
  printf("%d", _state);
 } while(0)
do{
  int _state = 0;
  if (NULL && NULL->member_)
    _state = NULL->member_->state_;
  printf("%d", _state);
 } while(0)
```

THIS code will be compiled. And now you can see for yourself what's the root cause of the compilation error.

Comment: C, OP mentioned C in the question. Although he did tag c++.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are just a text replacement.

for example, if you have

```
#define mac(x) x/x
```

that would work for must numbers but not for `0`, because it will be replaced with `0/0` which is not defined.

in your case if you pass `NULL` it will be replaced  with:

```
 do{ \
  int _state = 0; \
  if (NULL && NULL->member_) \
    _state = NULL ->member_->state_; \
  printf("%d", _state); \
 } while(0)
```

so what is the meaning of `NULL->member_` in this case. No sense, hence it fails.

consider using a regular function, or two macros one for regular pointers and one for `NULL` pointers, and make your code as this:

```
if (ptr)
   macro1(ptr);
else
   macro2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Small adjust let the pre-compiler know the type size + a forward declaration and it'll work:

```
#define macro1(arg1) \
 do{ \
  int _state = 0; \
  if ((arg1) && ((A*)arg1)->member_) \
    _state = ((A*)arg1)->member_->state_; \
  printf("%d", _state); \
 } while(0)
```

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A;

#define macro1(arg1) \
do{ \
  int _state = 0; \
  if ((arg1) && ((A*)arg1)->member_) \
    _state = ((A*)arg1)->member_->state_; \
  printf("%d", _state); \
} while(0)

struct member{
    int state_;
  };
class A {
  public:
  member* member_;
};


int main(int n, char** arg) {

  A* a = new A();
  a->member_ = new member();
  a->member_->state_ = 1;

  macro1(a);
  macro1(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The more fundamental problem is that `NULL` **is not a pointer**, it is a macro for 0.

Hence when you pass in `NULL`, it is equivalent to passing in 0, which of course is an error.

As other answers have mentioned, giving the argument an explicit cast will fix it

```
(A*)arg1
```

As a side note, you should be using `nullptr` in C++ for a null pointer.

**EDIT**: As @AjayBrahmakshatriya pointed out, `NULL` can be defined as `(void*)0` (in C only) which will be a pointer, but the argument still holds true, `NULL` is not a pointer of your type.

**EDIT2**: Apparently in C++11 and later, `NULL` can be defined as `nullptr`

Comment: The C standard doesn't say anything about NULL, but a null pointer which can be both integer constant 0 or integer constant casted to type `void*`. Now most implementations define NULL as `(void*)0`. So the problem here is because of the `->` operator on the type `void*`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I did *not* know that. Thanks.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Huh, but [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/3uyki) begs to differ, and also OP's error message says operand is not a pointer

Comment: [This](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ginclude/stddef.h) is the source for stddef.h in gcc. See line number 405. For c it is defined as (void*) 0 and for cpp it is defined as 0.

Comment: Again, this is one particular implementation. Others could do it otherway. I don't know about the cpp standard. Maybe it forces it be a integer constant 0.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Apparently yes the [C++ standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr) mandates that it be the integer 0

Comment: Great! This is a strong indication that OP is indeed using c++ and has wrongly titled his question.

Comment: Even the standard you linked for c++ states that - *A null pointer constant is an integer literal with value zero or a prvalue of type std​::​nullptr_­t*. I think this means that even in C++ nullptr contant can be of type pointer (std::nullptr_t).

Comment: `nullptr_t` is defined as the type of `nullptr` and its only value is `nullptr`. But from the wording, I think it meant that anything other than `nullptr` must be 0. Again the wording isn't the clearest, and I can't find a direct definition for `NULL`. Either way, `void*` is not implicitly convertible to other pointer types in C++.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) interpretation is `NULL` can be `nullptr`

Comment: Yes in c++ an explicit cast would be required to use nullptr as a pointer of other types. I am not very familiar with the c++ standard and its finer details.